# import content from notepad.txt to table.xlsx

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have a *.bat file that runs from python and it creates "file.txt" which contents more than two stings.
I'm trying pack the content from *.txt into varriable, and this var I want put into excell's table. But something goes wrong:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/Python_Projects/DateCollector 2/invert.py", line 86, in 
>       ws.append([username, pc_name, ip, phone, voip, dep, cur_data, laptop, laptop_sn, a])
>     File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 646, in append
>       cell = Cell(self, row=row_idx, column=col_idx, value=content)
>     File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 113, in **init**
>       self.value = value
>     File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 216, in value
>       self._bind_value(value)
>     File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 199, in _bind_value
>       raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
>   ValueError: Cannot convert ['яюS\x00A\x00M\x00,\x00S\x003\x00C\x003\x005\x000\x00,\x00H\x00T\x00N\x000\x000\x008\x009\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x00S\x00A\x00M\x00,\x00C\x007\x00H\x00G\x007\x00,\x00H\x00T\x00H\x00M\x005\x000\x000\x000\x001\x007\x00\n', '\x00\n', '\x00'] to Excel

Here is code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook      #excell module
import subprocess
filename = "1.xlsx"  #my excell with tabs
wb = load_workbook(filename) 
subprocess.check_call('monitor.bat', shell=True)  #running my *.bat and creating in root folder "note.txt" with two strings.
mon = open('note.txt')   #opening file.txt
monitors = mon.readline() #
ws.append([var1, var2 , monitors]) #try to put in tabs in excell
wb.save(filename) #save book
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to run the terminal/CMD command from Python, and read its output:

```
import os
#run command (and .read() reads the output of the command)
output = os.popen('wmic csproduct get name').read()
```

Comment: it is that I need. Thnx!

Comment: @CaiNSoUlMoN glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting / marking this post as answer. Happy coding!

Comment: You really shouldn't answer extremely poorly asked questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use PowerShell and run [`Get-ComputerInfo | Format-List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-computerinfo).

Comment: It lists information about operation system. I need info about devices.